# Open Windows Command Script with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

[image]Can I use a macro in Outlook to open a Windows Command Script file? The file I have is called Build_Order_File.CMD

I did try the Shell command but I got the error "Invalid procedure call or argument"
Here is what I tried

```
Dim Q2CFile
Q2CFile = Shell("C:\Users\SESA27956\Desktop\Build_Order_File.cmd", 1)
```

The attached image shows that it is expecting an = after the pathname.